# Eclipse for Android:Fail to launch emulator

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and facing the issue of launching the emulator in eclipse.

I've configure the SDK location with eclipse and installed Android Development Tool in eclipse too. But when I clicked on run in Eclipse tool bar, it prompt an error message as below:

> Couldn't launch the emulator! Make sure the SDK directory is properly setup and the emulator is not missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell eclipse where your SDK is. to do that got to window -> preferences -> android -> browse to find your sdk -> apply.

It should look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up an Emulator first on "Android Virtual Device Manager" . This is the image which looks like a phone with Android logo on it.

**EDIT:**

And make sure that you have the "emulator" under the tools folder in your Android SDK folder.

Try this if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download any Android API? just click on the SDK Manager (http://www.htcdev.com/images/uploads/devcenter/sdkmanager.png) and download an Android API (for instance 4.3 -API 18)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your path of `SDK's` are set properly in Eclipse
Goto `Window->Preferences->Click on Android->Click on Browse` select the path of where your `SDK's` are installed. Make sure that after the path is set you can see the list of `SDK's`